# PostgreSQL doesn't run on MacOS after OS upgrade

Tags: macos, postgresql

I had a postgreSQL v10 installed and running locally, now after I upgraded my macOS from Big Sur to Monterey now it seems the service is not running and I can't get it running. Brew doesn't recognize that it is installed, and I actually don't remember if I have installed it via Homebrew or not. I can't reinstall because I need the data from my databases, which seems to be located in the installation server rather than in /var/local directory.

My pg_env looks like this:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH
export PGDATA=/Library/PostgreSQL/10/data
export PGDATABASE=postgres
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGPORT=5432
export PGLOCALEDIR=/Library/PostgreSQL/10/share/locale
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/10/share/man
```

This is the last database logs I have:

```
2022-07-09 02:46:17.789 +03 [79] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2022-07-09 02:46:17.988 +03 [79] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 330) exited with exit code 1
2022-07-09 02:46:17.989 +03 [325] LOG:  shutting down
2022-07-09 02:46:18.452 +03 [79] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Have you check the system logs?

Comment: @RomeoNinov check my updated question